# Delete files with AppleScript to recycle bin or permanently

Tags: file, applescript, delete-file

I'm writing an AppleScript in which I want to insert a subroutine to delete specified files. With a flag I wish to control whether the given file is moved to the recycle bin or deleted permanently.

Actually my script looks like this:

```
on MyDeleteProc(theFile, allowUndo)
  if allowUndo then
    tell application "Finder" to delete POSIX file theFile
  else
    do shell script "rm " & theFile
  end if
end MyDeleteProc
```

Now I want to know if this case is correct so far or is there maybe another Finder command or a parameter for the delete command that I overlooked so I will be able to simplify the script above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppleScript is a temperamental beast, and the devil is often in the details.

While [@adayzdone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24721974/45375) provides the crucial pointer - use of the `System Events` application's `delete` command to achieve permanent deletion, working out the exact syntax takes trial and error:

**Caveat**: This handler works with both files and folders - targeting a *folder* with `allowUndo` set to `false` therefore *permanently deletes that folder's entire subtree*.

```applescript
on MyDeleteProc(theFile, allowUndo)
  if allowUndo then
    tell application "Finder" to delete theFile as POSIX file
  else
    tell application "System Events" to delete alias theFile
  end if
end MyDeleteProc
```

On OS X 10.9.4 I had to do the following to make this work:

- `Finder` context: Had to change `POSIX file theFile` to `theFile as POSIX file` (postfix form) - don't ask me why.
- `System Events` context: Using "cast" `alias` with the POSIX path provided is the only form of the command that worked for me.

---

That said, a little tweak to your original function would make it work, too (and unless you delete many files one by one, performance probably won't matter):

Note, however, that just using `rm` only works with *files* - if you wanted to extend it to folders, too, use `rm -rf` instead - the same **caveat re permanently deleting entire subtrees** applies.

```applescript
on MyDeleteProc(theFile, allowUndo)
  if allowUndo then
    tell application "Finder" to delete theFile as POSIX file
  else
    do shell script "rm " & quoted form of theFile
  end if
end MyDeleteProc
```

Note the use of `quoted form of`, which safely passes the file path to the shell, encoding characters such as spaces properly.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to execute `tell application "System Events"` with administrator privileges? In my specific case, I'd want to permanently delete an app from the `/Applications` folder.

Comment: @emkey08, you can try `do shell script "command" with administrator privileges` - see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Is it even possible to execute **any** `tell` command with administrator privileges, or do I always have to resort to using `do shell script` if something must be run as admin?

Comment: @emkey08, the only - limited - way I personally know of is to combine `do shell script` with an `osascript` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use System Events to permanently delete a file.