# Terminal: How to permanently remove a file off hard drive

Tags: terminal, applescript

So I have been creating a program that is essentially like a HelperBot and I want to add a feature where it deletes files from the hard drive completely instead of moving them to the bin and emptying the bin. I’m coding in AppleScript and here’s my code:
“do shell script “rm /user/Downloads/file.app/*””
Is this wrong or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete files with AppleScript to recycle bin or permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721329/delete-files-with-applescript-to-recycle-bin-or-permanently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*System Events* will delete files permanently without going via the Recycle bin:

```
tell application "System Events" to delete the file "/path/to/file.ext"
```

Or, to delete a folder:

```
tell application "System Events" to delete the folder "/path/to/folder"
```