# Cross platform move to trash

Tags: tcl

Is there a cross-platform way to move files to trash? `file delete` deletes the file completely and is not undoable on unixen. Even on Linux alone it's not straight forward to figure out the trash directory because it often depends on the file manager.

I've resorted to doing:

```
exec gio trash $file
```

The problem is that this only works on Gnome so even on Linux it is not cross-platform.

And as I don't have a Windows machine, figuring out how trash/recycle bin works in Windows is even more difficult

Answer (score 2):

The [FreeDesktop.org Trash specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html) says:

> For every user a "home trash" directory MUST be available. Its name
> and location are $XDG_DATA_HOME/Trash; $XDG_DATA_HOME is the base
> directory for user-specific data, as defined in the Desktop Base
> Directory Specification.

If $XDG_DATA_HOME is unset or empty, it defaults to $HOME/.local/share.

However, you can't just move files in and out of ~/.local/share/Trash. There are some metadata files involved that store the original location and timestamps. These metadata files are plain text, so they can be easily handled in Tcl.

So this sounds like it could be quite easily implemented in a Tcl module. But if such a module already exists, I'm not aware of it. It could be a nice project for someone learning Tcl.

**ADDED INFORMATION:**

As usual, [TWAPI](https://twapi.magicsplat.com/v4.4/index.html) to the rescue for Windows. The [twapi_shell](https://twapi.magicsplat.com/v4.4/shell.html) package has a `recycle_file` command.

Comment: But that still doesn't cover Windows and OSX

Comment: Hmm. I see that Gnome does not comply with this spec. On Ubuntu and Linux Mint which I am using the files go to `$HOME/Trash-${disk_uid}` instead. So for example on my laptop I have a folder `$HOME/Trash-1000`

Comment: I tend to ignore Windows and OSX, if at all possible. On windows it looks like you should be able to use twapi for this. The twapi_shell package has a recycle_file command.

Comment: Ah cool. That looks like a good place to start. OSX is fairly easy since how the trash works haven't changed since the beginning. That leaves us with all the variants of Linux/BSD/OpenSolaris where how the trash works depends on not only the window manager but file explorer

Comment: Do you perhaps use an encrypted home directory, so that it appears to be in a separate partition? The spec says: "If an $topdir/.Trash directory is absent, an $topdir/.Trash-$uid directory is to be used as the user's trash directory for this device/partition. $uid is the user's numeric identifier."

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it on macOS. This requires the [Tclapplescript](http://tclapplescript.sourceforge.net/) extension package:

```
package require Tclapplescript

proc trash args {
    set TRASH_CMD {
        tell application "Finder" to delete POSIX file "%s"
    }
    foreach file $args {
        set fullFilename [file normalize $file]
        set quoted [string map {\\ \\\\ \\" \\\\"} $fullFilename]
        AppleScript execute [format $TRASH_CMD $quoted]
    }
}
```

On recent versions of macOS, you'll need to grant appropriate permissions at runtime to let this work (or at least I had to when testing it).

See also:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50844/how-to-move-files-to-trash-from-command-line
- [Delete files with AppleScript to recycle bin or permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721329/delete-files-with-applescript-to-recycle-bin-or-permanently)

Comment: This is best read in conjunction with @SchelteBron's answer, which describes what to do for other platforms.

Comment: Also, finding the right Applescript incantation to use was _the_ hardest part of coming up with this answer; there's a lot of subtly wrong code out there, unfortunately… and I wonder how many OS revisions this one will be good for.